# Trouble storing use input text in react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to store the value of the color and the font size that the user has entered, but my program doesnt store the value, it changes it instantly when the user inputs text. I want it to change the font and background color when 'press me' is clicked. Here is what ive so far:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';
function Input(props) {
  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      style={{ height: 40, borderWidth: 1, padding: 20, paddingTop: 10, margin: 5 }}
      editable
      maxLength={40}
    />
  );
}
export default function InputMultiline() {
  const [mySize, setMySize] = useState('20');
  const [myBGColor, setMyColor] = useState('yellow');

  const colChange = () => {
    setMyColor(myBGColor);
    setMySize(mySize);
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: myBGColor.toLowerCase(),
        borderBottomColor: '#000000',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
      }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: Number(mySize) }}>Hello</Text>
      <View>
        <Input
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          value={myBGColor}
          onChangeText={colText => setMyColor(colText)}
        /></View>
      <View>
        <Input
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          value={mySize}
          onChangeText={sizeText => setMySize(sizeText)}
        /></View>
      <View style={styles.fixToText}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Button onPress={colChange}
            title="Press Me!"
            color="#841584" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginVertical: 8,
    fontSize: 20
  },
  fixToText: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 8,
    borderBottomColor: '#737373',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
  },
});
```

I have no clue how to change the font and background color together and click on 'press me'.

Comment: just hold them in temporary state, and after pressing the button update the original state .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add 2 more states that will contain user's input:

```
export default function InputMultiline() {
  const [mySize, setMySize] = useState('20');
  const [myBGColor, setMyColor] = useState('yellow');
  const [mySizeUserInput, setMySizeUserInput] = useState('20');  <---- ADDED
  const [myBGColorUserInput, setMyColorUserInput] = useState('yellow'); <----- ADDED


  const colChange = () => {
    setMyColor(myBGColorUserInput);  <----- CHANGED
    setMySize(mySizeUserInput);   <----- CHANGED
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: myBGColor.toLowerCase(),
        borderBottomColor: '#000000',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
      }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: Number(mySize) }}>Hello</Text>
      <View>
        <Input
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          value={myBGColor}
          onChangeText={colText => setMyColorUserInput(colText)}   <----- CHANGED
        /></View>
      <View>
        <Input
          multiline
          numberOfLines={4}
          value={mySize}
          onChangeText={sizeText => setMySizeUserInput(sizeText)}   <----- CHANGED
        /></View>
      <View style={styles.fixToText}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Button onPress={colChange}
            title="Press Me!"
            color="#841584" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Se tu

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue with your codes, in my case styles were broken so you can try to change the view by removing flex and adding height, like this:

```
<View style={{
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              backgroundColor: myBGColor.toLowerCase(),
              height: 100,
            }}>
```